# Upload image using VichUploaderBundle

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I have a problem with VichUploaderBundle, I followed all the instructions but I dont know how my Controller should handle this after finished form becouse image failed to uploaded and database did not write.

my Entity class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // ..... other fields

    /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     * 
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
     * 
     * @var File
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $imageName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $imageSize;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     *
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;

        if ($image) {
             var_dump($image);
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageName($imageName)
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImageName()
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $imageSize
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageSize($imageSize)
    {
        $this->imagesize = $imageSize;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return integer|null
     */
    public function getImageSize()
    {
        return $this->imageSize;
    }
}
```

my FormType class:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
class AvatarType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder


             ->add('imageFile', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Brochure (PDF file)'))

        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'avatar_form';
    }
}
```

config:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm # or mongodb or propel or phpcr
    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix:         /image/avatar
            upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/image/avatar'
```

Twig template:

```
<div>
      {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.imageFile) }}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
</div>
```

and finally Controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\User;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use AppBundle\Controller\InitController;
use AppBundle\Form\AvatarType;

class UserController extends Controller implements InitController
{
     /**
     * @Route("/user/avatar", name="AvatarAction")
     */
    public function AvatarAction(Request $request)
    {

      $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\AvatarType',null,array(
            // To set the action use $this->generateUrl('route_identifier')
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('AvatarAction'),
            'method' => 'POST'
        ));

      $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

            if($form->isValid()){

              //$track = new Product();
              //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
              //$em->persist($track);
              //$em->flush();
            }

      return $this->render('default/avatar.html.twig',array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your advice!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is not the solution, but your line :

```
 ->add('imageFile', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Brochure (PDF file)')):
```

Should be :

```
 ->add('imageFile', VichFileType::class, array('label' => 'Brochure (PDF file)'))
```

More info : https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/form/vich_file_type.md

What Symfony tells you as error ?

Have a nice day

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Stackoverflow is not a forum, please keep the structure of it. This is more a comment than an answer. When you have enough reputation you can post comment.